# Remapping global keybindings to a prefix command

Tags: key-bindings, commands, prefix-keys

The following works:

```
(define-prefix-command 'my-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-@") 'my-map) ;; MacOS
(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'my-map) ;; Windows 10
```

The following does not:

```
(global-set-key [remap set-mark-command] 'my-map)
```

It fails with the error that `my-map` is not a command (`commandp` returns nil).

The emacs manual states that "putting a remapping in a prefix keymap like `ctl-x-map` typically has no effect, as such keymaps are not themselves active;" however, I am remapping a command in the active global map to a prefix map. So why does this fail?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the use of `[remap COMMMAND]` syntax in a key-binding definition seems to require `COMMAND` to be a symbol that is a command (`commandp`).  It doesn't seem to allow a prefix-key keymap or a prefix-key variable whose value is a keymap.

I just sent a [mail to `emacs-devel@gnu.org`](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2019-09/msg00607.html) about this.  Maybe I'm missing something (probably).  But it seems like (1) the doc string of `define-key` says that it should work, but (2) it doesn't.

---

If you want, you can do almost the same thing this way:

```lisp
(substitute-key-definition 'set-mark-command 'my-map global-map)
```

That's almost the same thing as what you tried:

```lisp
(global-set-key [remap set-mark-command] 'my-map)
```

It does, in effect, what you ended up doing manually by binding each key individually.

The difference from remapping is that, well the command `set-mark-command` is not remapped.  Instead, you've just rebound each of its global keys to keymap (prefix command) `my-map`.

Comment: At least I'm not alone in being confused by this. I ended up settling for the less-than-elegant workaround of binding both C-SPC and C-@ to the map.